# Is $|z_1|^2 - |z_2|^2 = 1$ a conic section?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, reference-request

In complex analysis of one variable, I'm aware that $$||z-a|-|z-b||= 2c$$ is the equation of a hyperbola with foci $a,b$ such that $a, b, c \in \mathbb{C}$. Now if we move up in dimension, i.e. we consider $z= (z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2$, then is $$|z_1|^2 - |z_2|^2 =1$$ an equation of some type of conic section or perhaps a quadric surface, like a hyperbolic cylinder, for instance? Also, as a follow-up, if we consider $z= (z_1, z_2, z_3) \in \mathbb{C}^3$, then would $$|z_1|^2 - |z_2|^2 = |z_3|^2$$ be an equation of a conic section or quadric surface? I've never really studied complex analysis in several variables. Are there any good references that could point me toward something that might be useful for my two initial questions?

Comment: $|z| = a, a\in \mathbb{R}, z \in\mathbb{C}$ is a circle in the complex plane, maybe that can be some help

Comment: Oh I'm certainly clear on that point. Now in my first example, one thing I know is that if I replace the $-$ with $+$, then we have the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: No, if you replace $-$ by $+$ you get a (compact) sphere of dimension $3$ embedded in $\mathbb C^2=\mathbb R^4$. If you leave the $-$ minus sign alone, as in your question, you get a non-compact closed quadric of dimension $3$ in $\mathbb C^2=\mathbb R^4$. In both sign choices you obtain a hypersurface (=of dimension 4-1), not a surface (=of dimension 2).

Comment: Actually, I think I meant to say unit sphere if $-$ is replaced by $+$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: What about my follow-up question? Would that also be a hypersurface of dimension $3$?

Comment: It would be a real quadric hypersurface of dimension 5 in  $\mathbb C^3=\mathbb R^6$ . Your questions have nothing to do with complex analysis in several variables: they are questions on $\mathbb R^{2n}$ disguised as $\mathbb C^{n}$. A goood reference for real quadric hypersurfaces  in all dimensions is [Shilov's  Linear Algebra](http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/048663518X), at $9.47 .